# Align to the very right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code, for instance:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ntcg3/4/

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <p class="hey">hi</p>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.hey {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

​

There is still a bit of padding on the right side of the page.

How can I get rid of that padding so the red background color extends to the very end of the page?

Comment: hi.. Welcome to SO.. Can you please show us more code.. Or maybe, you could create fiddle at JSFiddle.net to show it live.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ntcg3/ is OK, but did you see that checkbox "Normalized CSS" checked by default?

Comment: i have no padding in your example, allways you can try CSS:
`body, .hey{margin:0; padding: 0}`

Comment: @user1653876: See my answer below for detail description of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an HTML page by default the `<body>` and some other elements like paragraph tags (`<p>`), heading tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>` .. `<h6>`) etc... has default `padding` and `margins`

So you need to clear those margin by adding following css:

```
html, body, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

For further details see [**CSS RESET**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

**An example of a CSS Reset:**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
display:block;
text-align:right;
```

you will get your require output

Answer (score 0):

Try using following CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
.hey {
    width:100%;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you should know, the browser adds its own styles to elements, and same as the margin created on ul tags, there is a margin created on the body tag. I would suggest inspecting elements first ( control + shift + c on most browsers ) so you become familiar with these generated styles, or there are many "reset" css files that remove the padding and margins or other such things from the styles first

In short though, if you include:
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
it will ensure that the html and body tag do not use up any margin or padding

Answer (score 0):

at the beginning of your css file you need to reset the values.

```
html, body, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead,  article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-weight:inherit;font-style:inherit;font-size:100%; }
```

It will reset your all default values to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting;

```
body,html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/AUmat/)*** is the working fiddle.